# What is more effective - mold control spray or the fogger?

Tags: mold, pest-control

Concrobium sells mold control spray and the fogger. Which one has more lasting effect on the mold? Does the $135 cost of fogger justify the effect it has on the mold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly applied spray is demonstrably more effective than fogging.

That being said, neither are good for use on the substrates where mold is often worst: wood and drywall.

In any case, the most effective means of addressing mold is physical removal and cleaning.